# Pulling data from a database for a C3js chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, c3.js

I wanted to know how do i pull data from a database
and creata a C3js chart. I have a script that does it and outputs a JSON object. In D3, I can do this using the D3.Json class. However I am not sure how to do this using the C3 library. I know that C3 is built on top of D3. I find C3 considerably simpler to create a chart. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [data.json](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-json) option?